# Why is this bitwise AND yielding incorrect numbers?

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation, bitwise-and

Why does Javascript incorrectly evaluate the following?

```
0xAABBCCDD & 0xFF00FF00
```

In Javascript:

```
console.log((0xAABBCCDD & 0xFF00FF00).toString(16)) // -55ff3400
console.log((0xAABBCCDD & 0xFF00FF00) === 0xAA00CC00) // false
```

In C++:

```
cout << hex << (0xAABBCCDD & 0xFF00FF00) << endl; // 0xAA00CC00
```

Comment: Use `console.log(((0xAABBCCDD & 0xFF00FF00) >>> 0).toString(16))` to work around it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Pointy pointed out in his answer, javascript uses signed 32-bit values. You can use `>>> 0` to indicate that the operation is to be unsigned.

```
console.log(((0xAABBCCDD & 0xFF00FF00) >>> 0).toString(16)) // Prints aa00cc00
```

Comment: You beat me to it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript bitwise operations involve a coercion to 32-bit values. Your values are being truncated.

*edit* — sorry; as the comment pointed out it's the sign bit that's the problem.

Comment: Isn't `0xAABBCCDD` a 32-bit value? This explains some other things, but not why this simple 32-bit operation is failing.

Comment: *Signed* 32-bit integers.